# Python interactive subprocess reading

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess

I have an interactive Windows console application that I communicate through `subprocess` module in my program. So far, the console commands(of the application) that I called from my script did not made any problems because they gave instant results(pipe outputs).

However there are other functionalities I need to use that **keeps printing output to the console until it recieves "stop" command.** I need to read those outputs, but my application is a **GUI** and I cannot let any hanging occur, and I don't want to get all the output after stop command is issued, I need to get it realtime, when it is served. I made some research and it appears this is a difficult problem to overcome(especially in Windows), but there are no recent questions about this topic.

I did find this,
[Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python), looks like what I am looking for.

But the answer seems really low-level for a Python solution and it is old. Are there any better-newer solutions for this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pexpect` is a library that could be used for nonblocking reading spawned process's output, but it's not that easy for Windows http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#windows

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin I've read about `pexpect`, however the Windows part and having absent methods gave me worry, because I do not know which functionalities are not usable.

Comment: Not for Python 2.7. In Python 3 you can use [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) to avoid blocking. However, if the problem is that the program itself buffers output when its stdout is a pipe, then there's no general solution for Windows. `pexpect` for Windows uses pipes and offers no solution to this problem.

Comment: Maybe you could redirect the program's output to a file and read and clean it with some interval? Makes a risk of losing some output though.